# react-query works with fetch, but not with axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch-api, react-query

I'm learning react-query and I built an example app using `fetch`, it works very well. But then the actual app in which I have to implement it uses `axios`.

So I converted `fetch` to `axios`. Like so:

[image]

https://github.com/rahulakrishna/chuck-norris-jokes-with-react-query/pull/1/files

It's behaving very unpredictably.

1. It's now making a lot more api calls. Even when the browser is idle
2. It doesn't really update when the queryDependencies change.

How to make `axios` work like `fetch`?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be specific to Axios only, but have you tried messing around with `refetchInterval` or `refetchOnWindowFocus`?

If not, I recommend reading about the useQuery options available [here](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/useQuery)